# Match row number prior at start of string

Tags: regex

I need to capture line number listed in below examples.

```
   9. X/KNOWN NUMBER - 245
  10. X/KNOWN NUMBER - 123
```

Each line may have 3 spaces in front (for #9) or 2 spaces in front (for #10).
The result I want is either 9 or 10

I have tried `^.+(?=KNOWN NUMBER)` , but my result is `9. X/ and 10. X/`.

Comment: Maybe `(?m)^\h*\K\d+(?=.*KNOWN NUMBER)`? See https://regex101.com/r/toHval/1

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

`^\s+(\d+)\.`

- `^`: Start of the line
- `\s+`: Match spaces in front
- `(\d+)`: Group to catch the number
- `\.`: Match literal period `.` after the number